# Why is the value of NSURLCreationDateKey nil on iOS 4.3 but not on iOS 5+?

Tags: ios, date, nsurl

I have a list of `NSURL`'s for local stored files.
I want to show the creation date, so I retrieve it as follows:

```
 for (NSURL * file in sortedFileList){
        NSDate *date = nil;
        NSError * error = nil;
        [file getResourceValue:&date forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error getting date: %@", error);
            continue;
        }
        if (!date)
        {
            NSLog(@"Empty date.... skipping file");
            continue;
        }
}
```

When I run this on iOS 5 simulator or iOS 6, it works ok and shows the dates.
However, when I run it on the iOS 4.3 simulator it gives me `nil` for the dates and logs for all files the "Empty date...." message.

According to the docs `NSURLCreationDateKey` is available from iOS 4, so what's going on?

Comment: +1 for both the question and the answer, this is a weird little detail, good to know.

Comment: Yes, still I need to find a way to make it work on iOS4 of course...

Comment: I agree with @H2CO3 - note that in a couple of days you'll be able to accept your own answer, which will help future users spot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the `getResourceValue: forKey:` method is only working on iOS 5+.

> Available in iOS 5.0 and later. (Symbol is present in iOS 4, but performs no operation.)

I don't yet understand why the `NSURLCreationDateKey` is available for iOS 4, cause I can't find any method to get the date from the NSURl on another way.

Solution for now:

```
NSDate *date = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[url path] 
    error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];
```

Comment: Or, you could just drop iOS 4 support (the only devices that are left on it are those with ARMv6, which you can no longer compile for).

Comment: Well, you can compile for armv6 with a little bit of work. But indeed, if you don't want to support armv6 then you can leave it.